# Get & Post in ASP.NET Blazor

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.1, blazor, blazor-server-side

With the help of a few samples available on the internet, I am able to develop a ASP.NET Core Hosted Blazor Application.

But While Calling an api as follow

```
 private async Task Refresh()
{
    li.Clear();
    li = await Http.GetJsonAsync<SampleModel[]>("/api/Sample/GetList");
    StateHasChanged();
}

private async Task Save()
{  
   await Http.SendJsonAsync(HttpMethod.Post, "api/Sample/Add", obj);     
   await Refresh();
}
```

In the line below:

```
await Http.SendJsonAsync(HttpMethod.Post, "api/Sample/Add", obj);
```

How can I check status code of this HTTP call?

If there occurs any problem in API call than I want to display a message.

But when I do:

```
 HttpResponseMessage resp = await Http.SendJsonAsync(HttpMethod.Post, "api/Sample/Add", obj);
```

Then it says:

> can not cast void to `HttpResponse` Message

I am using below methods:

```
GetJsonAsync() // For HttpGet
SendJsonAsync() // For HttpPost And Put
DeleteAsync() // For HttpDelete
```

How can I verify the status code here ?

Answer (score 8):

The thing is that you are using blazor's [`HttpClientJsonExtensions`](https://github.com/dotnet/blazor/blob/0.1.0/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor/Json/HttpClientJsonExtensions.cs) extensions,

Which internally usually calls

```
public static Task SendJsonAsync(this HttpClient httpClient, HttpMethod method, string requestUri, object content)
    => httpClient.SendJsonAsync<IgnoreResponse>(method, requestUri, content);

public static async Task<T> SendJsonAsync<T>(this HttpClient httpClient, HttpMethod method, string requestUri, object content)
{
    var requestJson = JsonUtil.Serialize(content);
    var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(new HttpRequestMessage(method, requestUri)
    {
        Content = new StringContent(requestJson, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
    });

    if (typeof(T) == typeof(IgnoreResponse))
    {
        return default;
    }
    else
    {
        var responseJson = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return JsonUtil.Deserialize<T>(responseJson);
    }
}
```

The GET requests use `HttpContext.GetStringAsync` internally

```
public static async Task<T> GetJsonAsync<T>(this HttpClient httpClient, string requestUri)
{
    var responseJson = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(requestUri);
    return JsonUtil.Deserialize<T>(responseJson);
}
```

while the normal `HttpClient` API still exists and can be used just as in those extension methods.

Those extension methods simply wrap the default `HttpClient` calls.

If you desire to have access to response status you would need to write your own wrappers that expose the desired functionality or just use the default API

Comment: Just as a remark, the link in the post does not work anymore. The current address is:
https://github.com/dotnet/blazor/blob/0.1.0/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor/Json/HttpClientJsonExtensions.cs

Moreover the Blazor has been moved to the ASP.NET Core repo.

Comment: @MaciejKlemarczyk thank you for the update. I have used the link you provided to fix the broken the link in the post.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
 var response = await Http.SendJsonAsync <HttpResponseMessage>(HttpMethod.Post, "api/Sample/Add", obj);
```